# Fetch keys of existing hash and give them default values

Tags: ruby, hash, fetch

Given an existing hash such as:

```
{
  "April_data" : {
    "April" : 10,
    "May" : 8,
    "June" : 7,
    "July" : 7,
    "August" : 5,
    "September" : 2
  },
  "May_data" : {
    "May" : 4,
    "June" : 3,
    "July" : 2,
    "August" : 2,
    "September" : 0
  },
  "June_data" : {
    "June" : 12,
    "July" : 12,
    "August" : 8,
    "September" : 2
  }
}
```

How can I proceed in order to preserve all the keys contained in 'April_data' in other months and assign default values such as '0'? So the result would look like:

```
{
  "April_data" : {
    "April" : 10,
    "May" : 8,
    "June" : 7,
    "July" : 7,
    "August" : 5,
    "September" : 2
  },
  "May_data" : {
    "April": 0,
    "May" : 4,
    "June" : 3,
    "July" : 2,
    "August" : 2,
    "September" : 0
  },
  "June_data" : {
    "April": 0,
    "May": 0,
    "June" : 12,
    "July" : 12,
    "August" : 8,
    "September" : 2
  }
}
```

Any help apreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" is applicable. We want to know what sort of effort you've put into solving the problem. Did you search sites and not find answers? If so, where and how did those pages fail to answer the question? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, where is the minimal example demonstrating the problem? Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stub = hash.each_with_object({}) do |(_, v), memo|
  memo.merge!(v)
end.map { |k, v| [k, 0] } # or end.keys.product([0]).to_h
   .to_h
#⇒ {"April"=>0, "May"=>0, "June"=>0, "July"=>0, "August"=>0, "September"=>0}

hash.map { |k, v| [k, stub.merge(v)] }.to_h
#⇒ desired result
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to remember that hashes will overwrite existing keys, so start with the default and overlay them with the ones you want to keep:

```
DEFAULTS = {
  "April" => 0,
  "May" => 0,
  "June" => 0,
  "July" => 0,
  "August" => 0,
  "September" => 0
}

data = {
  "April_data" => {
    "April" => 10,
    "May" => 8,
    "June" => 7,
    "July" => 7,
    "August" => 5,
    "September" => 2
  },
  "May_data" => {
    "May" => 4,
    "June" => 3,
    "July" => 2,
    "August" => 2,
    "September" => 0
  },
  "June_data" => {
    "June" => 12,
    "July" => 12,
    "August" => 8,
    "September" => 2
  }
}

data.each do |k, v|
  data[k] = DEFAULTS.merge(v)
end
```

Which results in:

```
require 'ap'
ap data

# >> {
# >>   "April_data" => {
# >>     "April"     => 10,
# >>     "May"       => 8,
# >>     "June"      => 7,
# >>     "July"      => 7,
# >>     "August"    => 5,
# >>     "September" => 2
# >>   },
# >>   "May_data"   => {
# >>     "April"     => 0,
# >>     "May"       => 4,
# >>     "June"      => 3,
# >>     "July"      => 2,
# >>     "August"    => 2,
# >>     "September" => 0
# >>   },
# >>   "June_data"  => {
# >>     "April"     => 0,
# >>     "May"       => 0,
# >>     "June"      => 12,
# >>     "July"      => 12,
# >>     "August"    => 8,
# >>     "September" => 2
# >>   }
# >> }
```

If you're not sure what the keys should be, or, if you're like me and are lazy and want to let Ruby define the defaults for you, you can scan the sub-hashes and let Ruby figure it out:

```
DEFAULTS = data.flat_map{ |k, v| v.keys}.uniq.map{ |k| [k, 0] }.to_h
# => {"April"=>0, "May"=>0, "June"=>0, "July"=>0, "August"=>0, "September"=>0}
```

Here's what that's doing:

```
DEFAULTS = data
          .flat_map{ |k, v| v.keys} # => ["April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "June", "July", "August", "September"]
          .uniq # => ["April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September"]
          .map{ |k| [k, 0] } # => [["April", 0], ["May", 0], ["June", 0], ["July", 0], ["August", 0], ["September", 0]]
          .to_h
# => {"April"=>0, "May"=>0, "June"=>0, "July"=>0, "August"=>0, "September"=>0}
```

Alternately, but not necessarily faster or more concise:

```
DEFAULTS = data.values # => [{"April"=>10, "May"=>8, "June"=>7, "July"=>7, "August"=>5, "September"=>2}, {"May"=>4, "June"=>3, "July"=>2, "August"=>2, "September"=>0}, {"June"=>12, "July"=>12, "August"=>8, "September"=>2}]
               .flat_map(&:keys) # => ["April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "June", "July", "August", "September"]
               .uniq # => ["April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September"]
               .map{ |k| [k, 0] }.to_h  # => {"April"=>0, "May"=>0, "June"=>0, "July"=>0, "August"=>0, "September"=>0}
```